# Checking if each digit is divisible by 2

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a C program to ask the user to enter in a pin code and checks if each digit in the number is divisible by 2. For instance, if they enter 123452 it tells the user that it is wrong because 1,2,3,5 isn't divisible by 2. If I enter 642642 it says it is fine but if I enter in 622248 it displays invalid number, which is wrong because every digit in 622248 is divisible by 2. How can I fix this error?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 6 

int main(void)
{
    int num, digits[N], i, invalid, count = 1, sum = 0;

    TOP:
    printf("Enter pin code (attempt %d): ", count++);
    scanf("%d", &num);

    invalid = num;
    // stores each digit of the number entered into the the array
    for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
        digits[i] = num % 10;
        num = num / 10; 
    }
    // if the user enters more than 6 digits than it will give you an error.
    if (digits[N] > 6) {
       printf("Code %d is invalid!\n", invalid); 
       goto TOP;
    } 
    // loops through the array elements and see if each digit is divisble by 2, if not then print an error.
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if (digits[i] % 2 != 0) {
            printf("Code %d is invalid!\n", invalid); 
            goto TOP;
        }
        else {
            printf("Congratulation, code %d is valid!\n", invalid);
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to take the input as a string. Will simplify it significantly.

Comment: Note: all that is needed to check if a number is divisible by two is `n & 1 == 0`

Comment: You're breaking from your last loop when the first digit appears to be divisible by 2. You want to print that the code is valid after all iterations have passed the test.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Agreed :) - See my answer

Comment: @GovindParmar Well, you have taken it to the extreme :)

Comment: Using the label `TOP` and `goto TOP;` is generally not regarded as a good idea.  Use an explicit `while` or `for` loop instead. In limited circumstances, branching forwards to go to an exit or error handling label is fine.  Using `goto` to form a loop is not such a good idea.

Comment: regarding: `because 1,2,3,5 isn't divisible by 2`  Actually, the 2 is divisible by 2. So there is a bad assumption in the premise for the algorithm

Comment: what if the user only enters 5 (or less) digits or enters 7 (or more) digits?  the posted code does not check for these unexpected conditions.  I.E. never trust the user to do the right thing

Comment: regarding: `if (digits[N] > 6) {`  In C, the valid offsets in an array are 0...(number of elements in array -1).  So `digits[N]` is accessing 1 past the end of the array.  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {`  When 'i' is 6, this is accessing beyond the end of the array: `digits[]`  The result is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: it is good programming practice to limit the scope of a variable as much as possible.  Therefore, this statement: `int ..., i, ...;` should have the 'i' variable removed and change statements like: `for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {` to `for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {`

Answer (score 4):

If you are permitted to process the input as a string, rather than an integer, all that is needed is [`strspn`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/) to determine the validity of the digits in the pin and [`strlen`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to determine the validity of the length:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t len = strlen(str_pin);
if (len <= 6 && strspn(str_pin, "24680") == len)
{
    puts("Valid pin");
}
else
{
    puts("Invalid pin");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with how you're storing the digits:

```
for (i = 6; i >= 0; i--) {
    digits[i] = num % 10;
    num = num / 10; 
}
```

The length of the array `digits` is 6, meaning that valid indexes go from 0 to 5, but you start reading into index 6.  This writes past the bounds of the array invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Change the loop to start at 5.

```
for (i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
    digits[i] = num % 10;
    num = num / 10; 
}
```

This check is also invalid:

```
if (digits[N] > 6) {
```

Because it again reads past the end of the array.  Even if it did not read past the end, you're checking if an element of the array is greater than 6, not if there are more than 6 digits.

You divide `num` by 10 in a loop to get the digits, so if this value is non zero then you know there are too many digits.

```
if (num > 0) {
```

Comment: I would mention that if you count down the way you did, `i` must always be `signed` number otherwise you end up in dead-end (in this case this is ok as `i` is `int`). To avoid such scenario, `for (i = 6, i > 0; i--)` and then `digits[i - 1] = num % 10;`.